# angular karma tests fails, custom tag is not a knows element

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am learning angular and my first karma test throws the error below.

```
AppComponent should create component
Error: Template parse errors:
'ereturn-form' is not a known element:
1. If 'ereturn-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ereturn-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ereturn-form></ereturn-form>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0
```

This are my modules and components

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { EreturnService } from './ereturn.service';

import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { EreturnFormComponent}  from './ereturn-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule,
  InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, EreturnFormComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ EreturnService ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<ereturn-form></ereturn-form>',
})
export class AppComponent  { }
```

ereturn-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { Ereturn } from './ereturn';
import { EreturnService } from './ereturn.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'ereturn-form',
  templateUrl: './ereturn-form.component.html'
})

export class EreturnFormComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

this is my specs file

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

Why is karma complaining about the custom html tag ? angular compiles and runs it just fine.

thank you very much

Comment: where is the spec file code? update it to post

Comment: thanks @Aravind, I just added the spec file

Comment: one line is not enough. add the complete spec file you might have made mistakes in he module creation of your spec file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your element is a custom component, you should add it to your test as part of declarations.

```html
import { CustomElement } from '...your path here';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [ ],
      declarations: [CustomElement],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });
```

If you want to ignore that specific element, you can ignore it by adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your schema array:

```html
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
      declarations: [],
      imports: []
    });
```

And at last, if it comes from another library you should add it's module to your test:

```html
import { CustomeModule } from 'module name here';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [  ],
      declarations: [],
      imports: [CustomeModule]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });
```